# Psycopg write list to STDIN to copy_expert

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to write data to a postgres table using the psycopg copy_expert function

I have a list of lists which looks like

```
[[0,'sdg',121, 4.2], [12,'abc',2, 7.9]]
```

(In reality it is a very large list of lists)

I want to convert this to a buffered CSV format so that I can use the COPY operator in postgres.

```
data = [[0,'sdg',121, 4.2], [12,'abc',2, 7.9]]
buffer = StringIO()

 # How do I transform 'data' to y ?
 writer.writerows(y)
 buffer.seek(0)

 with conn.connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor) as cur:
      cur.copy_expert(f"COPY <table_name> FROM STDIN WITH CSV", buffer)
      conn.connection.commit()
```

I DO NOT want to use pandas.to_csv because of some limitations of this project.

Answer (score 0):

you were close. here's the relevant section of docs for `.copy_from()`: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from

```py
import io, csv

# `data` into CSV format in-memory
buf = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(buf)
writer.writerows(data)

# now back to beginning of buffer to provide file-like in-memory object
buf.seek(0)

# note that you need to specify "," because the default separator is "\t"
with conn.cursor() as cur: 
    cur.copy_from(buf, "your_table_name", sep=",")

conn.commit()
```